# Prove that $(A,B)$ is uncontrollable $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\exists P$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{nxn}$, $P \neq 0$: $PA - AP = 0$, $PB=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

In my course advanced system Theory I had the following question:

Prove the following equivalence for the pair $(A,B)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ x $\mathbb{R}^{nxm}$:

$(A,B)$ is uncontrollable $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\exists P$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{nxn}$, $P \neq 0$: $PA - AP = 0$, $PB=0$.

Hence, in terms of alternatives, either the pair $(A,B)$ is controllable, or there exists a nonzero matrix $P$ such that $PA-AP=0$ and $PB=0$.

I proved this as shown in the attachment. I think that my prove is 100% complete. My teacher, however, disagreed with this and explained that I only prove this statement from left to right and not from right to left. I did not understand his explanation about why my prove is incomplete. I even think that my proof is correct.

Can someone explain me whether my proof is complete. If it is incomplete, then can someone also explain me what I am missing and how to prove the part that I miss?

Page 1:
[image: page 1 of my proof]

Page 2:
[image: page 2 of my proof]

Answer (score 1):

$P$ doesn't have to be constructed using $P=e_r e_\ell$ as your professor stated. There may be some $P$ that do satisfy the conditions and not has the form $P=e_r e_\ell$. You need to prove that *any* nonzero $P$ cannot satisfy $PA-AP=0$ and $PB=0$ if $(A,B)$ is controllable.

Here is that part of the proof:

> $e_\ell (A - \lambda I) = 0$ for the left eigenvector $e_\ell$ of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ by definition. Also $e_\ell B \neq 0$ for any left eigenvector $e_\ell$ of $A$ by the controllability assumption. This means if $P (A - \lambda I) = 0$ for some nonzero matrix $P$ and some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, the rows of $P$ must consist of the left eigenvectors of $A$, which implies that $P B \neq 0$.

Comment: Cevabin icin tesekkur ederim kardes. I am not sure if I understand this correctly. You are almost saying the same as I did. The only difference is that you are not saying anything about the columns of P. Is this the only thing that is my mistake?

Comment: The fact that $P$ cannot be constructed as $P=e_r e_\ell$ doesn't imply that there is no nonzero $P$ such that $P(A-\lambda I)=0$ and $PB = 0$. It only implies that there is no such matrix of the form $P=e_r e_\ell$.

Comment: Now I see thank you. You are saying that P must be of the form $P=x e_l $. Where x is any vector. The mistake I make is to say that x "must be" $e_r$. Thank you. (Diger sorumada goz atabilirseniz memnun olurum).

Comment: No, if you create $P$ by multiplying two vectors, it will have rank 1. But you required to show that for *any* $P$, with any rank.